# In list of vectors, select vectors which have specific values in R

Tags: r, select, subset, apply

I want to select only a and b vectors in list of vector (e), How can I do?

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(1,2,3,5,3)
c <- c(6,4,5,3,3)
d <- c(6,3,2,3,4)

e <- list(a,b,c,d)
```

##results

```
res
##a, b
```

---

a and b have 1, so I just want to select which has specific values (can be one or multiple).

If I want to select vectors which have c(2,3).

Comment: Try `e[1:2]`, or name your list `e <- list(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d)`, then `e[c('a', 'b')]`.

Comment: Oh, i just forget about why I want to select a,b. I just want to vectors which have containing specific values c(1,2).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to select all vectors that contain 1 or 2, this will work:

```
e[sapply(e, \(x) all(any(grepl(1, x)), any(grepl(2, x))))]
```

However, I'm not sure if you're seeking a more generic solution.